# Symfony2: Stateless Authentication set to true, session still being created

Tags: symfony

I followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#stateless-authentication and set the flag to true. However, a session is still being created. I'm currently using PdoSessionStorage for storing the sessions if that makes any differences.

```
firewalls:           
    api_area:
        pattern:  ^/api/
        stateless:  true
        http_basic:
            realm: "RESTful API"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What other bundles are being used in different areas of your site that may be using sessions?  In particular there is an issue with the FOS Facebook bundle that starts a session even if Facebook login is not used.

Comment: I'm using FOSUserBundle, WebProfilerExtraBundle, FOSJsRoutingBundle, VichUploaderBundle. Let me try with the prod environment to see if its creating sessions.

Comment: And yep, it's still creating sessions with auto_start set to false and in the prod environment... so that waves off the possibility of the web profiler needing any sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Update: With [#2200](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/1640) (Symfony 2.1) the configuration option `framework.session.auto_start` doesn't exists anymore. The session now always starts on demand as long as the `php-ini`-settings are appropiate.

"stateless authentication" means, that it doesn't use sessions for authentication, but this does not mean, that there will be no session at all. Especially with

```
framework:
    session:
        auto_start: true
```

there will always be an active session

Also note the notice on the page you have linked

> If you use a form login, Symfony2 will create a cookie even if you set stateless to true.

Comment: I have auto_start set to false for both php.ini and in my config.yml. I'm also using basic http authentication for this particular context area. My only question is that, if authentication is not reliant on the session at all - is there any side effects for having a session in the first place (other than take up entries in my pdo storage?)

P.S. on the same page, it says: "no cookie will be ever created by Symfony2" with that flag set

Comment: this solution is deprecated !

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps anyone else who is struggling with this "Symfony2 always seems to start a session, even if PHP has auto-start set to 0 and apparently Symfony2 is configured to not auto start sessions"...

I found that the code I had for displaying flash messages (if they existed) was in fact starting a session if it didn't exist - on every page.

I had:

```
{% for type, flashMessages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
   {% for flashMessage in flashMessages %}
     <div class="alert alert-{{ type }}">
       {{ flashMessage }}
     </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and the process of asking for the flashbag on the session object, auto starts the session if it doesn't yet exist.

If I wrap the code block above in:

```
{% if app.session.started %}
   ...
{%endif%}
```

the problem goes away.

This was causing a lot of unnecessary performance overhead - because the unnecessary setting of the PHP Session cookie meant my caching strategy for non-logged in pages was broken.

Hope this helps

Comment: You could use the `NullSessionHandler` to get rid of sessions without bothering about your code. Its FQN is `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NullSessionHandler` and you can see how to use a custom session handlere here: [Symfony Cookbook: How to Use PdoSessionHandler to Store Sessions in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html). Simply replace the `session.handler.pdo` definition with something like `session.handler.null` using the above mentioned class.

Comment: Didn't know about `app.session.started` in the doc it is said to use `app.request.hasPreviousSession`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-the-session